# Change text style (to bold) in custom style resource for collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, textstyle

I am using a collapsible toolbar in a project and I am trying to set the `textStyle` of the expanded collapsing toolbar title to **bold**.

For some reason I can change pretty much anything using a custom text appearance except `textStyle`. Does anyone have any information about that issue? I found it hard to search in the internet. I tried programmatically to no avail neither.

```
<!-- style resource -->
...
<style name="Toolbar_Title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/detail_title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
...

<!-- layout file -->
...
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="16dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar_Title"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one works for me. Having defined the text appearance in the layout file for the collapsing toolbar I can use the `setExpandedTitleTypeface` function to add a bold style to the currently used type face:

```
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTypeface(Typeface.create(mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getExpandedTitleTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD));
```

The attribute `textStyle` does not seem to be taken into account by the collapsing toolbar.

A disadvantage is that the collapsing toolbar by default *ellipsizes* the title, which may not be a desired behaviour in some cases.